# WooCommerce: Change default country on the cart page

Tags: plugins, session

I'd like to change the default country on the **cart** page to *none*, i.e. to have "Select a country…" appear as the default in the drop-down list of countries.

I've looked at [this WooCommerce Docs snippet](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/change-the-default-state-and-country-on-the-checkout/) which uses the `default_checkout_country` **filter** but it only seems to apply to the **checkout** page (and not the **cart** page), as its title says. I also tested this by surrounding the `apply_filters('default_checkout_country', ...` in the files where they appear with `echo` statements and they don't appear anywhere in the generated markup for the **cart** page.

As we are using PayPal Express Checkout we don't use the WooCommerce built-in checkout page so it appears that the above mentioned snippet doesn't apply and another solution is needed.

My next step was to look into `woocommerce/templates/cart/shipping-calculator.php` where the country option list is generated on the **cart** page. There's a call to `$woocommerce->customer->get_shipping_country()`. That function in `woocommerce/classes/class-wc-customer.php` simply picks up the `$_SESSION['customer']['shipping_country']` variables. The only place those variables are set is in the function `set_shipping_to_base()` in the same file and the only place that function is (conditionally) called is in `woocommerce/shortcodes/shortcode-cart.php` which I assume generates the **cart** from the **shortcode** used on the autogenerated **cart** page. I added a `echo` statement to the block in that file where that function is called but nothing appeared in the markup, so I got stuck there.

The above investigation seems however to be somewhat of a red herring as the above mentioned session variables seem to actually be set by the **Base Country/Region** setting on the General tab, as it would vary accordingly when the `$_SESSION` variable got printed in a browser where cookies and cache had been previously deleted. So I'm kind of stuck here too. I'd like the **Base Country/Region** setting to remain the country set, but still have no default country unless the visitor actually has selected it.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not an answer, but I've come to realise that the country chosen in the calculator has no bearing on the final shipping price. When using **PayPal Express Checkout** the shipping price is actually calculated on the shipping country returned from PayPal (which is the same as the billing country if a different shipping address is not entered). This make the matter quite a bit less pressing for us.

Comment: See this code by MikeJolly:
https://gist.github.com/mikejolley/2974310 Hope it helps you as much as it helped me :)

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue, but need to set country to US, here is how I fix it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart' , 'set_country_befor_cart_page'); 

function set_country_befor_cart_page(){

    WC()->customer->set_billing_country('US');
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country('US');
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

By chance and just plain putzing around, I've come up with this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'default_country_fields' );

function default_country_fields( $fields ) {

 $_SESSION['customer']['country'] = 'Select a country...';
 $_SESSION['customer']['shipping_country'] = 'Select a country...';

 return $fields;
}
```

As you can see, I'm simply setting the $_SESSION variables as needed. I'm kind of a n00b at this so, I'm unaware yet if there are any negative repercussions to this method. And there's probably a more appropriate hook or filter for this, but what I used I got from here:

[tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters](http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/snippets/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-2)

If you are not logged in or have no billing/shipping info set to your account, you will correctly see the default values for billing/shipping country. However, when logged in with a user account that has billing or shipping info set, this function will be overridden and the defaults selected will reflect that of your user account billing info.